# Wiring a ceiling fan with a light kit

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

I have a ceiling fan with a light kit. Black, white, blue and green are on the fan and black, white and copper from the house. Pretty easy, but where does the blue go to?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have separate wall switches for the fan and light, or aren't using a remote, the blue gets attached with the two blacks.

In this case you must use the pull chains to control the light and fan separately. Other than a remote there is no way to control them separately.